# Stop iOS scroll on DIV overlay appear

Tags: jquery, ios, overflow, overlay

I'm using Media Queries to make a Nav overlay appear on screen widths less than 40em. I have my `.mobile-nav` appearing (and disappearing) when `.mobilemenu` is clicked using a small bit of JQuery

```
jQuery('.mobilemenu').click(function(e) {
    jQuery(this).toggleClass('is-active');
    jQuery('.mobile-nav').toggleClass('active');
    jQuery('body').addClass('noscroll');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

The problem I'm having is that when this is activated the page behind is still scrolling, but ideally I want it to be fixed in position. I've tried using `.addClass` as you can see above, which appends a `.noscroll` class with `overflow: hidden;` but this seems to work perfectly when simulated on a browser (except the class is not removed so then the page is stuck!) but on iOS it does not work at all.

I'm sure there must be a more simple elegant solution that actually works! If anyone has any idea that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered and expanded upon [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33213493/enabling-disabling-touchmove-on-click)

But for reference, code is below:

```
jQuery('.mobilemenu').click(function(e) {
    jQuery(this).toggleClass('is-active');
    jQuery('.mobile-nav').toggleClass('active');
        if(jQuery('.mobile-nav').hasClass('active')) {
            $('body').on('touchmove', false);
        } else  {
            $('body').off('touchmove', false);
        }
});
```