# Enabling/Disabling touchmove on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently building a site with a really simple overlay effect - I have a 'hamburger' (`.mobilemenu`) menu icon, which when clicked toggles a pseudo class on my navigation overlay (`.mobile-nav`). I'm looking to add some code which also disables `touchmove` on the initial click and when (`.mobilemenu`) is clicked again, reinstates the default behaviour.

This is my code as it stands:

```
jQuery('.mobilemenu').click(function(e) {
    jQuery(this).toggleClass('is-active');
    jQuery('.mobile-nav').toggleClass('active');


    e.preventDefault();
});
```

I tried the following:

```
jQuery('.mobilemenu').click(function(e) {
    jQuery(this).toggleClass('is-active');
    jQuery('.mobile-nav').toggleClass('active');
    if('.mobile-nav').hasClass('active') {
        $(body).on('touchmove', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        }};

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

This obviously isn't working!

Frankly Javascript/JQuery is quite new to me, so I'm sure the syntax is incorrect here. Could I potentially toggle a body class that has touch move disabled? Or do I have to somehow rewrite the code and use `bind`?

**EDIT:** On the suggestion of @John R I've changed the syntax of my code slightly - Here is a fiddle: [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jameshenry/xbgu406a)

My code now looks as follows:

```
jQuery('.mobilemenu').click(function(e) {
  jQuery(this).toggleClass('is-active');
   jQuery('.mobile-nav').toggleClass('active');
     if(jQuery('.mobile-nav').hasClass('active')) {
     $(body).on('touchmove', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
  }};

e.preventDefault();
});
```

However this seems to have killed the overlay completely! I'm guessing that though the line `if(jQuery('.mobile-nav').hasClass('active')) {` etc. is now correct, the following bits might not be?

**EDIT 2**: So after a bit of playing around I've updated the syntax, the overlay is again working but I can still scroll the body of the page behind the overlay on iPhone: http://jsfiddle.net/jameshenry/bzau0jaz/1/ - If anybody has any ideas I'd really appreciate that!

```
jQuery('.mobilemenu').click(function(e) {
    jQuery(this).toggleClass('is-active');
    jQuery('.mobile-nav').toggleClass('active');

    if(jQuery('.mobile-nav').hasClass('active')) {
        $(body).on('touchmove', function(e){
            e.preventDefault()}
                  )};
});
```

**EDIT 3**: After playing around with the structure and syntax a little more I've finally got the 'touchmove, false' working when clicked. The only problem is it doesn't toggle so scrolling is permanently disabled!

```
jQuery('.mobilemenu').click(function(e) {
    jQuery(this).toggleClass('is-active');
    jQuery('.mobile-nav').toggleClass('active');

    if(jQuery('.mobile-nav').hasClass('active')) {
        $('body').on('touchmove', false);
    };
});
```

I'm thinking an Else statement is the way to go, but  I've tried adding the following:

```
jQuery('.mobilemenu').click(function(e) {
    jQuery(this).toggleClass('is-active');
    jQuery('.mobile-nav').toggleClass('active');

    if(jQuery('.mobile-nav').hasClass('active')) {
        $('body').on('touchmove', false);
    };
    else { $('body').on('touchmove', true);};
});
```

But that just seems to stop the overlay working - is there a way to switch 'touchmove' back on when closed? Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jameshenry/bzau0jaz/2/

Comment: Correct your syntax as mentioned by John R. and also try css `Pointer-events:none` Declare a class with the style and toggle on condition. https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/pointer-events/. Supported on modern browsers. For IE 9 browser Javascript is the only way..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok the solution (after lots of trial and error and way too many hours spent on this!) is really simple - binding using `.on()` and unbinding via `.off` - Here is the final jQuery code:

```
jQuery('.mobilemenu').click(function(e) {
    jQuery(this).toggleClass('is-active');
    jQuery('.mobile-nav').toggleClass('active');
        if(jQuery('.mobile-nav').hasClass('active')) {
            $('body').on('touchmove', false);
        } else  {
            $('body').off('touchmove', false);
        }
});
```

If anyone can see any flaws in this approach or ways to neaten it up that would be great. Seems to be working nicely though!

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
if('.mobile-nav').hasClass('active'){
  //...
}
```

To

```
if(jQuery('.mobile-nav').hasClass('active')){
   //...
}
```

Comment: I've amended the code as per your suggestion, but I think I'm still going wrong somewhere as my overlay is now not working at all - I've dropped it into a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jameshenry/xbgu406a/

My code looks as follows:
`jQuery('.mobilemenu').click(function(e) {
    jQuery(this).toggleClass('is-active');
    jQuery('.mobile-nav').toggleClass('active');
    if(jQuery('.mobile-nav').hasClass('active')) {
        $(body).on('touchmove', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        }};

    e.preventDefault();
});`

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget $ or "jQuery" before all Element selection in jQuery ... to make an If Statement work, it needs to be

```
if (true) { ...something };
```

So for yours 
      jQuery('.mobile-nav').hasClass('active') === true

So You need to encapsulate it in parentheses , so

`jQuery('.mobile-nav').hasClass('active')` 
needs to be in parentheses...

```
if(jQuery('.mobile-nav').hasClass('active')){
    //doSomething
}
```

Comment: Updated with correct syntax but still not working unfortunately -http://jsfiddle.net/jameshenry/bzau0jaz/1